# Ziping of file from one folder to another using vbscript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, zip

Please check what is wrong with the below code. I'm trying to zip the file of one folder and placing it in other folder. I have 94 files but out of that only 80 to 82 or like that some files are zipping. I am using a `.bat` file:

```sh
@setlocal
@echo off

set TIMESTAMP = %DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~10,4%

::CD C:\Desktop\Batchscripts\TESTZIP

::md C:\Desktop\Batchscripts\TESTZIP\%TIMESTAMP%

ECHO ------- BEGIN zip ----------------

CScript  "C:\Desktop\Batchscripts\TESTZIP\zip.vbs"  "C:\Desktop\Batchscripts\%TIMESTAMP%\"  C:\Desktop\Batchscripts\TESTZIP\%TIMESTAMP%.zip

ECHO All production export xml files are completed. please find the location C:\Desktop\Batchscripts\TESTZIP\%TIMESTAMP%.zip

Pause

IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (goto :error)

ECHO ------- END zip------------------
```

which is calling a VBScript:

```vbs
'Get command-line arguments.
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments

InputFolder = objArgs(0)
ZipFile = objArgs(1)

'Create empty ZIP file.
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items

objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source)

'Required!
wScript.Sleep 2000
```

Comment: zip.vbs code:

'Get command-line arguments.
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
InputFolder = objArgs(0)
ZipFile = objArgs(1)

'Create empty ZIP file.
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateTextFile(ZipFile, True).Write "PK" & Chr(5) & Chr(6) & String(18, vbNullChar)

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set source = objShell.NameSpace(InputFolder).Items

objShell.NameSpace(ZipFile).CopyHere(source)

'Required!
wScript.Sleep 2000

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: I saw you also used the same code, could you please check what could be the possible problem here for not taking all the files.

Comment: Please do not post code in comments, because it's bound to become unreadable. Edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: Sorry Ansgar, it wasnt allowing me to paste both the code together as i was in hurry in hurry so pasted the rest code in comment, i will format the question and again post here in some time.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your VBScript doesn't wait long enough. Try increasing the value to 5000 or 10000 milliseconds.

The Problem with the `CopyHere` method is that it runs asynchronously, i.e. it returns immediately instead of waiting until the operation is finished. However, the `Shell.Application` object is automatically destroyed when the script exits, thus terminating an ongoing `CopyHere` operation. If that operation wasn't completed at that point, your zip archive will be a couple files short.

Comment: Hello Ansgar, yes it worked this time, thanks for your help, i will try it for different number of files.